# Error while making azure speech to text api call via python

Tags: python, azure, http, azure-functions, speech-to-text

I am trying to use Azure speech to text api, through python. Below is the code.

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<my_subscription_key>',
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
  "contentUrls": [
      "<URI_TO_MY_AUDIO_FILE>",
  ],
  "properties": {
  },
  "locale": "en-US",
  "displayName": "Transcription"
})

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/speechtotext/v3.0/transcriptions?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

The error I am getting is:

```
b'{\r\n  "code": "InvalidPayload",\r\n  "message": "Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: }. Path \'\', line 1, position 5."\r\n}'
```

I believe I am setting my parameters wrong. Unable to find what's wrong.

Python version 3.7

Strangely the same HTTP request is successful when done via https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/CreateTranscription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your POST request body is not supplied in the right format.
Please see the corrected code below:

```
import http.client
import json

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<my_subscription_key>',
}

body = {
  "contentUrls": [
      "<URI_TO_MY_AUDIO_FILE>",
  ],
  "properties": {
  },
  "locale": "en-US",
  "displayName": "Transcription"
}

try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("POST", "/speechtotext/v3.0/transcriptions", body=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend switching to using the Python API rather than the REST API;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-python

That looks like a weird error that could even be being caused by something in your audio file, so swapping to the Python API would probably give you a more useful error message.

Comment: Using SDK, Can you share how to transcribe files stored as blob on azure? I can see an example with local file, but unable to find an example with blob uri

Comment: Ah, apologies, I missed that detail of your initial question. I know there is a Python API for Azure Blob storage, but I am afraid I've never used it. I'd recommend adding the **azure-blob-storage** tag to your question and calling that out specifically, cause that makes this significantly trickier.

Comment: In addition to using blob uri, I also do not want to deal with different audio file files. The HTTP call takes care of it. I don't have to worry about codecs.